# Hibernate как правильно связать три таблицы последовательно

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть три таблицы:forms, groups, fields. таблицы forms и groups связаны один ко многим forms.id - groups.form_id. таблицы groups и fields связаны один ко многим groups.id - fields.group_id. Т.е. я могу выполнить такой запрос,который вроде бы правильный:

```
select f.name, g.name, fl.name
from forms f
left join groups on f.id = g.form_id
left join fields on g.id = fl.group_id
```

теперь с помощью jpa hibernate я аннотирую поля в классах InputForm, InputGroup, InputField

-- в классе InputForm

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = InputGroup.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "inputForm")
    private Set<InputGroup> inputGroups;
```

-- в классе InputGroup

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", nullable = false)
    private InputForm inputForm;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = InputField.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "inputGroup")
    private Set<InputField> fields;
```

-- в классе InputField

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", nullable = false)
    private InputGroup inputGroup;
```

но при выполнении rest запроса неправильно вытаскиваются json объекты

вот структура таблиц

```
create table s_input_forms(
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    name_1 varchar(255),
    name_2 varchar(255),
    name_3 varchar(255),
    serial_number int,
    version int,
    primary key (id)
)
engine = InnoDB;

create table s_input_groups(
    id bigint not null auto_increment,
    name_1 varchar(255),
    name_2 varchar(255),
    name_3 varchar(255),
    serial_number int,
    form_id bigint,
    is_multi_group tinyint(1),
    height int,
    primary key (id),
    foreign key (form_id) references s_input_forms(id)
)
engine = InnoDB;

create table s_input_fields(
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
   name_1 varchar(255),
   name_2 varchar(255),
   name_3 varchar(255),
   serial_number int,
   group_id bigint,
   field_type varchar(255),
   length int,
   row_count int,
   dictionary_id bigint,
   is_key tinyint(1),
   is_enabled tinyint(1),
   is_visible tinyint(1),
   primary key (id),
   foreign key (group_id) references s_input_groups(id)
)
engine = InnoDB;
```

тестовые данные

```
insert into s_input_forms(id, name_1, version) values(1, 'formname1', 1);
insert into s_input_groups(id, name_1, form_id) values(1, 'group1', 1);
insert into s_input_fields(id, name_1, group_id) values(1, 'field1', 1);
```

а вот то, что я получаю в ответе

```
[{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":[{"id":1,"name1":"group1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"inputForm":{"id":1,"name1":"formname1","name2":null,"name3":null,"serialNumber":null,"version":1,"inputGroups":
```

Comment: А что значит не правильно вытаскиваются объекты? Выложите тогда данные, ваш запрос, то что вы ожидали увидеть и результат который получили. Судя по запросу вы связи правильно написали. Только можете targetEntity убрать

Comment: данные получаю из сервиса @Override
    public List<InputForm> getAllForms() {
        return inputFormRepository.findAll();
    }

Comment: выложите вместо запроса структуру таблиц, может так станет более понятно. И лучше сущности целиком

Comment: данные получаю из сервиса @Override
    public List<InputForm> getAllForms() {
        return inputFormRepository.findAll();
    } вот тестовые данные insert into s_input_forms(id, name_1, version) values(1, 'formname1', 1); insert into s_input_groups(id, name_1, form_id) values(1, 'group1', 1);
insert into s_input_fields(id, name_1, group_id) values(1, 'field1', 1); должно быть [{id:1,name1:formname1, inputGroups : [{id : 1, form_id: 1, fields : [{id : 1, name1: field1, group_id : 1}]}]}] , а получаю непонятно что на одну страницу

Comment: Понятно что вы получаете, зацикленные данные. Вам нужно разорвать циклы с помощью аннотации `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: А в идеале создать трансферные объекты, которые вы будете передавать через REST. Это сделает API более независимым от внутренний структуры объектов и избавит вас от подобных проблем с циклами.

Comment: большое спасибо. помогло

Comment: спасибо за совет по трансферным объектам. будем изучать)

Comment: По сути это обычные POJO объекты, вы в них указываете только то что хотите передать через рест, и пишите классы-мапперы, которые из Entity делают трансферные объекты и наоборот.

Comment: Я оформил как ответ, чтоб закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понятно что вы получаете, зацикленные данные. Вам нужно разорвать циклы с помощью аннотации `@JsonIgnore`. А в идеале создать трансферные объекты, которые вы будете передавать через REST. Это сделает API более независимым от внутренний структуры объектов и избавит вас от подобных проблем с циклами. По сути это обычные POJO объекты, вы в них указываете только то что хотите передать через рест, и пишите классы-мапперы, которые из Entity делают трансферные объекты и наоборот.

Comment: Я так понял, что правильно создавать промежуточные классы (копии Entity). А можно где-то посмотреть пример как это делать?